# 301 Redirect via .htaccess (w/ Examples)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I currently have a Linux Dedicated Server and I would like to 301 Redirect several versions of my domain name (and its files/directories) to the **https://** version via .htaccess. My goal is to have ONE version of my domain no matter how it is typed and no matter what file and/or subdirectory is trying to be reached.

What I am seeking...

1. http:// example.com >> **https**:// example.com
2. http:// www.example.com >> **https**:// example.com
3. https:// www.example.com >> **https**:// example.com

Examples of files/directories...

- http:// example.com/1.jpg >> **https**:// example.com/1.jpg
- http:// www.example.com/sub/ >> **https**:// example.com/sub/
- https:// www.example.com/sub/1.jpg >> **https**:// example.com/sub/1.jpg

Notice how everything 301's to https://example.com ?

**Lets pretend I have a completely blank .htaccess file and would like to accomplish this set-up. How should my code look like? I really do not have a .htaccess file and  0 add-ons or customization to my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This is the ONLY code that fully nails what I was seeking. Thank you very much; worked perfectly. Thank you.